# Get current call status of Microsoft Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

On my Windows PC, I've installed the Microsoft Teams app. I'd like to find out with an appropriate API whether I'm actually in a call and whether my microphone within a call is muted or not.

So my questions are:

1. How can I find out whether I'm currently in a call?
2. What is the current microphone state within a call (muted / unmuted)?

A little bit of background: I want to implement a little .NET Core service that polls for these information in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can get user status using [Graph API presence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) request, in response body you will get status.

   GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/presence

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 1574

{  
    "id": "fa8bf3dc-eca7-46b7-bad1-db199b62afc3",
    "availability": "Available",
    "activity": "Available"
}
```

2. To know current microphone state within a call (muted / unmuted) is not possible.

There is a get [participant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/participant-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API to get microphone state but for this you need to create a [calling bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot) in teams, create a call in that bot and then from created call using call ID you can get participant microphone state using GET `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/calls/{id}/participants/{id}`

Comment: Thank you! But how does for example Jabra handle my second question - they seem to be able to read that information so that they can display a red or green LED on the headset whether I'm muted or not. Do they use a calling bot?

Comment: @mu88 - By defualt teams will use device Mic and speakers. If we want we can change the device settings to custom device like headset and using that we can control the mic. Currently there is no api to get the current microphone state within a call. we recommend you to raise a Teams UserVoice [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) if this needs to be consider as a future request.